# Trying to create an SQL Procedure but getting errors

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a new SQL procedure and am getting a syntax error. I am not the greatest with SQL so I am sure I have an error in there somewhere. Can someone tell me what is wrong with it? thanks for any help.

```
create PROCEDURE `p_provider_get_distributors_by_sort`(varOffset INT(11), varSortName varchar(50), varSortDirection varchar(6))
BEGIN
SET @st := concat('(SELECT id FROM distributor WHERE status = "AC") ORDER BY 'varSortName, varSortDirection' LIMIT 100 OFFSET ', varOffset);
PREPARE stmt FROM @st;
EXECUTE stmt;
END //
```

Comment: Notice: your stored procedure is wide open to SQL injection due to generation of your statement by concatenation with varchar input parameter.

Comment: what do you suggest to fix this.

Comment: I suggest having the proc just have the select happen. Why exec inside?

Answer (score 0):

You missed lot of things in your sp
first of all, You have to add prefix `'@'` with all your parameters
Secondly, You must have to declare your `@st` object